# onBackPressed() android with fragments

Tags: java, android

Good evening. My application starts with splash screen activity, for this activity I use `android:noHistory="true"` (I also use noHistory for MainActivity). My MainActivity is `android.support.design.widget.NavigationView. Inside onCreate()` method I use `showMethod()` to draw Home fragment (home page) .
So, when I click back button it works absolutely fine, app remembers all fragments which were open in correct order. *But!* when I click back button on my home page(which was opened after application start) it shows me empty screen with previous activity title.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    showHome();
}
Fragment fragment = null;

private void showHome(){
    fragment = new Home();
    if (fragment != null){
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_main , fragment,fragment.getTag());
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }

}


@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    int count = getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();

    if (count == 0) {
        super.onBackPressed();

    } else {
        getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    }
}


private void displaySelectedScreen(int id){


    switch (id){
        case R.id.nav_cafe_restaurants:
            fragment = new Cafe_restaurants();
            break;
        case R.id.nav_cinemas:
            fragment = new Cinemas();
            break;
        case R.id.nav_enjoys:
            fragment = new Enjoys();
            break;
        case R.id.nav_night_clubs:
            fragment = new Night_clubs();
            break;
        case R.id.nav_theaters:
            fragment = new Theaters();
            break;
        case R.id.nav_museums:
            fragment = new Museums();
            break;
        case R.id.nav_sports:
            fragment = new Sports();
            break;
        case R.id.nav_sights:
            fragment = new Sights();
            break;
        case R.id.nav_current_actions:
            fragment = new Current_events();
            break;
        case R.id.nav_future_actions:
            fragment = new Future_events();
            break;
        case R.id.nav_contacts:
            fragment = new Contacts();
            break;

    }


    if (fragment != null){
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_main , fragment,fragment.getTag());
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

}
```

You may check 2 screenshots to understand my problem.Trying to solve few hours by myself.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/33L1a.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1zBN.jpg)

Comment: when you click back button it shows previous activity with black button so you want if you click back button app close ?

Comment: yes. I suppose it remembers activity. Because I have about 8 framents in NavigationView and when I click on them and click back button after, it pops  them in correct order fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you're adding the intial `Home` `Fragment` to the back stack. That means that the transaction from "no fragment" to "Home" can be undone. When you press the back button, you'll pop that transaction from the stack which will leave you with no `Fragment` displayed.

Simply remove `fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);` from your `showHome()` method.

Comment: Thank you sir! It works. I will accept your answer in few minutes ( 7 mins delay)